# Chrome extensions are not showing in popup window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Do any one knows how to make sure that extensions work in popup window as well.

I have my chrome browser[highlighted with RED rectangle box in the picture], I wanted to capture the full screen of popoup windows[which is below to chrome highlighted box]. Also to mention that popup page is very huge having big scroll in it [mentioned by blue arrow in the picture].

[image]
Its really important.

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab or chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia. You'll have to scroll the window programmatically and repeat the capture, then stitch the screenshots if needed. Another method is to use chrome.debugger API and Page.captureScreenshot method but it's limited to 16384px height. Use a google search or similar site to find the existing extensions/examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for reply, I used all the extension available like "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?hl=en" and etc but all of them are not working for pop up page.

Comment: Try asking in a different forum because StackOverflow is about programming, software search is off-topic.

Comment: This is a very good, unanswered question. Any one has found a solution meanwhile?

Answer (score 4):

Right click the Google Chrome window on top and select open as tab, then the address bar opens with default options to the right and click the puzzle icon for your extensions :)

[image: a snapshot of the browser icon bar including the puzzle icon, along with the pop-up menu]

Comment: Do you maybe know if this behavior can be set as a default in the Google Chrome configuration somewhere?